# Flutter/Firebase - Merge 2 streams and utilise result in PageView Builder

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream

I am trying to take two streams of data from firebase and merge them into one, then use in my PageView builder in my flutter app. I have managed to get my first stream working (default occasions) but I now need to add another. Here are the two streams:

```
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> getDefaultOccasions(BuildContext context) async*{
  yield* Firestore.instance.collection('datestoremember').document('default').collection('Dates_to_Remember').snapshots();
}

Stream<QuerySnapshot> getPersonalOccasions(BuildContext context) async*{
  final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
  yield* Firestore.instance.collection('datestoremember').document(uid).collection('Dates_to_Remember').snapshots();
}
```

I'm not sure the best way to merge the two streams together and then use the result in a Page View Builder:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: getDefaultOccasions(context),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
              return new PageView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.5),
              onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(() => _index = index),
              itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                return Transform.scale(
                  scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.5,
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 6,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(snapshot.data.documents[i]['Date'].toDate().day.toString()),
                        Text(DateFormat.MMMM()
                            .format(
                            formatter.parse(snapshot.data.documents[i]['Date'].toDate().toString()))
                            .toString()),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                          child: FittedBox(
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data.documents[i]['Title'],
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );},
          ),
```

Here is all the code:

```
class AccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AccountPageState createState() => _AccountPageState();
}

class _AccountPageState extends State<AccountPage> {
  List<Category> _categories = [
    Category('My History', Icons.history, MyHistory()),
    Category('Dates to Remember', Icons.event_note, DatesToRemember()),
    Category('Terms and Conditions', Icons.assignment, TermsandConditions()),
    Category('Privacy Notice', Icons.security, PrivacyNotice()),
    Category('Rate us', Icons.stars, RateUs()),
    Category('Send us Feedback', Icons.feedback, GiveUsFeedback())
  ];

  DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');

  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 75, // card height
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: getDefaultOccasions(context),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if(!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
                  return new PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.5),
                  onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(() => _index = index),
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                    return Transform.scale(
                      scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.5,
                      child: Card(
                        elevation: 6,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(snapshot.data.documents[i]['Date'].toDate().day.toString()),
                            Text(DateFormat.MMMM()
                                .format(
                                formatter.parse(snapshot.data.documents[i]['Date'].toDate().toString()))
                                .toString()),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                              child: FittedBox(
                                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                child: Text(
                                  snapshot.data.documents[i]['Title'],
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );},
              ),
            ),
          ),
//          SizedBox(height: 100.0,),
          Container(
            // Page Options
            height: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .height * 0.7,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _categories.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          _categories[index].icon,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        title: Text(_categories[index].name),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                        onTap: () =>
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                    _categories[index].route)),
                      ),
                      Divider(), //                           <-- Divider
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}

Stream<QuerySnapshot> getDefaultOccasions(BuildContext context) async*{
  yield* Firestore.instance.collection('datestoremember').document('default').collection('Dates_to_Remember').snapshots();
}

Stream<QuerySnapshot> getPersonalOccasions(BuildContext context) async*{
  final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
  yield* Firestore.instance.collection('datestoremember').document(uid).collection('Dates_to_Remember').snapshots();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Merge your two Streams like this:

```
StreamGroup.merge([getDefaultOccasions(context), getPersonalOccasions(context)]).asBroadcastStream();
```